# Excel VBA WorksheetFunction in custom function (not sub)

Tags: function, excel, vba

As far as I can tell, Excel wont let you use WorksheetFunctions in a vba FUNCTION (NOT A SUB or SUBROUTINE). Is there a way to use WorksheetFunctions in a FUNCTION? If not, is there simple alternative to get the same results as the COUNTA function? Does anyone know why WorksheetFunctions don't seem to get along with custom functions?

```
Function CountIfsFast(range1 As range, val1, Optional range2 As range, Optional val2)
    rangesize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range1)
    range1array = RangetoArray(range1)
    range2array = RangetoArray(range2)
    matchcount = 0
    For i = 0 To rangesize
        If range1array(i) = val1 Then
            If range2array(i) = val2 Then
                matchcount = matchcount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    CountIfsFast = matchcount
End Function
```

Update: I figured out the problem, sort of. See my answer below.

Comment: If `range1` is already a range object, the `CountA` line should be `rangesize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range1)`

Comment: Just google before making any assumptions :)

Comment: What are you basing your assumption on? Does your function just not work? It seems quite possible it's erroring out elsewhere. For example the code doesn't seem to account for `range2` or `val2` not having been passed in, or the error could be in `RangeToArray`. Put a break on the first line and try stepping through the function.

Comment: @DataAnalyst OK, I have written "*a function using a WorksheetFunction*" and it works fine for me.  It's something else in your code/sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm sure its the WorksheetFunction causing the error. Try writing a simple function using a WorksheetFunction. It returns a generic "application-defined or object-defined error" According to Microsoft: a function cannot "Set properties or execute most methods." -http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787 Unfortunately, Microsoft is characteristically vague about which methods cannot be used. Once again, this is function, which has different rules/limitation from a subroutine. I can't find any reason why this is happening other than Excel just wont allow it in functions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Can you share your code? What version of Excel are you using. I can't get any of them to work. I'm using Excel 2010. Even the simplest:
Function mytest(cell)
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin (cell)
End Function

Comment: @Santosh Thanks for the suggestion :P Try Googling WorksheetFunction in Excel vba FUNCTION or anything similar. Everything that comes up relates to Subroutines.

Comment: @DataAnalyst the `WorksheetFunction.CountA` works perfectly for me, when called from within a Function. I am using Excel 2010 on Win 7 64b.

Comment: Upload the images to Dropbox, include the URLs in the post, and I (or someone else with enough privilege) can insert the images in the Question body.

Answer (score 0):

This "custom" function returns the same value as the built in CountA function (in 2007 at least).  You'll have to give a bit of detail around the range you're passing in your function for us to help you debug.

```
Function counta2(rng As Range)
     Dim i As Integer

     i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)

     counta2 = i

End Function
```

And you use it like:  =counta2(C1:C8)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me too: (Excel 2010)

```
Public Function fubu(range1 As Range) As Variant
    Dim rangesize As Variant

    rangesize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range1)

    fubu = rangesize
End Function
```

Try cutting and pasting this in literally: with absolutely no changes, then call it from a sheet formula.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your function works, but for some reason it still shows an error in the cell and in the VBA debugger. That is, I get the correct output in the "Function Arguments" window when I click the "Insert Function" button, but when I click "OK" the cell shows an error instead of the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify it to get rid of the `RangeToArray` function which you did not include.  Note that I changed the to specify the data type of its return value `As Long`.  I also declare variables of specific data types. This would be a good habit to start :)

[image: screenshot]

```
Function CountIfsFast(range1 As Range, val1, Optional range2 As Range, Optional val2) As Long
    Dim range1Array As Variant
    Dim range2Array As Variant
    Dim rangeSize As Long
    Dim matchCount As Long
    Dim i as Long

    rangeSize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range1)
    range1Array = range1
    range2Array = range2
    matchCount = 0
    For i = 1 To rangeSize
        If range1Array(i, 1) = val1 Then
            If range2Array(i, 1) = val2 Then
               matchCount = matchCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    CountIfsFast = matchCount
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, sort of. I thought it was a restriction of functions, because in my case, I could use WorksheetFunctions in subroutines, but not in functions. Turns out that had nothing to do with it. Researching the 50290 error further, I stumbled across this in another forum:

"I came across this - its a Microsoft bug. You need to find the problematic object on one of your forms or whatever it is (button, picture, label, etc) and delete it."

I did some experimentation and found that something in my collection of functions is causing Excel to freak out when I call WorksheetFunctions. To get them working again, I have to completely close out Excel and start a new workbook. When I do that, the WorksheetFunctions work fine. Strange.